# angular ng-repeat creating multiple forms syntax error

Tags: angularjs, forms, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm ng-repeating over a collection of items, and each item I want to have its own form and its own submit button, which will send that form info to the submit function. I needed to know which item is being submitted, so I figured I'd create one form per item and that would indicate which one is being submitted. Currently, it's in an li ng-repeat like so:

```
<input ng-model="query" type="text" placeholder="Filter by" autofocus>
<ul class="gNow">
    <li ng-repeat="item in selRole.selectRoles | multifilter:query">
        <form name="selRoleForm-{{item.rowId}}" ng-submit="selRole.selectRole(selRoleForm-{{item.rowId}})" novalidate>
            <div class="card">
                <p>Card Name: {{item.cardName}}</p>
                <p>.. other form elements here ..</p>
                <p><button type="submit">Select</button></p>
            </div>
        </form>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I'm getting the following error:

> [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token '{' invalid key at column 33 of
>   the expression [selRole.selectRole(selRoleForm-{{item.rowId}})]
>   starting at [{item.rowId}})].

What am I doing incorrectly - or is there a better way to approach this problem?

[This SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22091052/angularjs-ng-repeat-creating-multiple-forms) is the closest that I could find to my problem, but still, I'm not sure I understand how to adjust to my specific needs.

**UPDATE:**
Thanks to all the responses which lead me to the solution. I needed to not include the form name in the submit function, but the item instead. That was all that was missing.

old (syntax error):

```
ng-submit="selRole.selectRole(selRoleForm-{{item.rowId}})"
```

new (working):

```
ng-submit="selRole.selectRole(item)"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just store the form name in your ng-repeated array:

```
<input ng-model="query" type="text" placeholder="Filter by" autofocus>
<ul class="gNow">
    <li ng-repeat="item in selRole.selectRoles | multifilter:query">
        <form name="{{item.formName}}" ng-submit="selRole.selectRole(item.formName)" novalidate>
        ...
```

Comment: This fixed the syntax error, which pointed me in the right direction. This allowed me to see the real problem, which was not passing the correct object in the ng-submit function. Added update to question with solution.

Answer (score 1):

Use ngForm :

```
<div class="form-group" ng-repeat="item in selRole.selectRoles | multifilter:query">
  <ng-form name="userFieldForm">
    <label></label>
    <input >
  </ng-form>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to reverse the conversion in the concatenation of the names.
When parsing a parameter on ng-submit what you need to convert is the hard-coded string, not the rowId.

would be something like that:

```
<input ng-model="query" type="text" placeholder="Filter by" autofocus>
<ul class="gNow">
<li ng-repeat="item in selRole.selectRoles | multifilter:query">
    <form name="selRoleForm-{{item.rowId}}" ng-submit="selRole.selectRole('selRoleForm-'+item.rowId)" novalidate>
        <div class="card">
            <p>Card Name: {{item.cardName}}</p>
            <p>.. other form elements here ..</p>
            <p><button type="submit">Select</button></p>
        </div>
    </form>
</li>
```